# show div only if have a related post inside

Tags: posts, conditional-tags, featured-post

I want to have a related box to show up - but only if a related post is inside the div.
If theres no post the whole "related_box" div should be not shown. Any idea?

Here's the code so far.

```
    <div id="related_box" class="related">
    <div class="movie_header">
    <div id="featured"><h2>Related</h2>

    </div>
    <?php
    global $post;
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'movies', 'string');
    $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID;

    if(!empty($terms)){
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            query_posts( array(
            'movies' => $term->slug,
            'showposts' => 4,
            'caller_get_posts' => 1,
            'post__not_in' => $do_not_duplicate ) );
            if(have_posts()){
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID; ?>
    <div class="related">
    <div class="inner">
    <div class="thumb"><?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) the_post_thumbnail('movie-thumb'); ?></div>
    <h2 class="description">
   text</h2>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h1 class="title" ><?php the_title(); ?> </h1></a>


    </div>
    </div>
                <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query();
            }
        }
    }
    ?>

    </div>


    </div>
```

thanks!
AD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move the div section from the start to after the `if(have_posts()) {` line, and move the corresponding closing divs to just before the closing bracket `}` of this if statement;

full code:

```
<?php     
global $post;     
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'movies', 'string');     
    $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID;      
    if(!empty($terms)){         
        foreach ($terms as $term) {             
        query_posts( array(             
            'movies' => $term->slug,             
            'showposts' => 4,             
            'caller_get_posts' => 1,             
            'post__not_in' => $do_not_duplicate 
            ) );    

            if(have_posts()){ ?>
        <div id="related_box" class="related">     
        <div class="movie_header">     
        <div id="featured"><h2>Related</h2>      
        </div>          
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
            $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID; ?>     
            <div class="related">     
                <div class="inner">     
                    <div class="thumb"><?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) the_post_thumbnail('movie-thumb'); ?></div>     
                <h2 class="description">text</h2>     
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h1 class="title" ><?php the_title(); ?> </h1></a>   
                </div>     
            </div>                 
            <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>        
        </div>       
        </div>          
            <?php } //ends: if(have_posts())
        }     
    }     
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It might sound odd ... but you are so close

in fact a standard single.php template usually has a loop like this. Basically you put your `<div>related posts</div>` as part of your wp_query loop.

you should start with something like

```
<?php new wp_query
if has_post {
echo '<div>';
}

else{
// do nothing
}
```

Comment: Hi Damien thanks for the reply but it doesn't work for me...